# Pretty Printing (2D Arrays, Box)

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have written the following code:

```
for row in range(len(listOfLists)):
    print('+' + '-+'*len(listOfLists))
    print('|', end='')
    for col in range(len(listOfLists[row])):
        print(listOfLists[row][col], end='|')
    print(' ') #To change lines 
print('+' + '-+'*len(listOfLists))
```

Input:

> ```
> [['a', 'b', 'c'],
>  ['d', 'e', 'f'],
>  ['g', 'h', 'i'],
>  ['j', 'k', 'l']]
> ```

Output:

> ```
> +-+-+-+-+
> |a|b|c| 
> +-+-+-+-+
> |d|e|f| 
> +-+-+-+-+
> |g|h|i| 
> +-+-+-+-+
> |j|k|l| 
> +-+-+-+-+
> ```

Desired Output:

> ```
> +-+-+-+
> |a|b|c| 
> +-+-+-+
> |d|e|f| 
> +-+-+-+
> |g|h|i| 
> +-+-+-+
> |j|k|l| 
> +-+-+-+
> ```

Which prints a '+-+' around the elements of the 2D array.
However, my code only works for a square array (n^2).

How can I generalise it so that it works for any variation of array (as long as all lists are equal length)

Thank you

Comment: please indent your code

Comment: Can you, please, proper format code and put example what you get and what you want?

Comment: @vishes_shell that too :-)

Comment: @345243lkj Sorry!!! I fixed it! :)

Comment: @vishes_shell I am really sorry for the unclear format. I fixed it now! :)

Comment: @Saadat `len` of subbarays is the same?

Comment: @vishes_shell yes, the subarrays will always have the same length. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was that `len(listOfLists)` was used for the size of the printed table in both directions. `len(listOfLists)` defaults to number of rows, by doing `len(listOfLists[0])` you get the number of columns.

```
 listOfLists = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
     ['d', 'e', 'f'],
     ['g', 'h', 'i'],
     ['j', 'k', 'l']]

for row in range(len(listOfLists)):
    print('+' + '-+'*len(listOfLists[0]))
    print('|', end='')
    for col in range(len(listOfLists[row])):
        print(listOfLists[row][col], end='|')
    print(' ') #To change lines 
print('+' + '-+'*(len(listOfLists[0])))
```

output:

```
+-+-+-+
|a|b|c| 
+-+-+-+
|d|e|f| 
+-+-+-+
|g|h|i| 
+-+-+-+
|j|k|l| 
+-+-+-+
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Good catch. Fixed to account for that

Comment: @345243lkj Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are printing this separator based on number of rows, not number of columns. Using additional test cases helps with debugging immediately.

```
def printListOfLists(listOfLists):
    for row in range(len(listOfLists)):
        print('+' + '-+' * len(listOfLists[0]))
        print('|', end='')
        for col in range(len(listOfLists[row])):
            print(listOfLists[row][col], end='|')
        print(' ')  # To change lines
    print('+' + '-+' * len(listOfLists[0]))


printListOfLists([
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    ['j', 'k', 'l']
])

printListOfLists([['a', 'b', 'c']])

printListOfLists([['a'], ['b'], ['c']])
```

All produced results are now expected:

```
+-+-+-+
|a|b|c| 
+-+-+-+
|d|e|f| 
+-+-+-+
|g|h|i| 
+-+-+-+
|j|k|l| 
+-+-+-+


+-+-+-+
|a|b|c| 
+-+-+-+


+-+
|a| 
+-+
|b| 
+-+
|c| 
+-+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
def awesome_print(listOfLists):
    for row in range(len(listOfLists)):
        print('+' + '-+'*len(listOfLists[row]))
        print('|', end='')
        for col in range(len(listOfLists[row])):
            print(listOfLists[row][col], end='|')
        print(' ') #To change lines 
    print('+' + '-+'*len(listOfLists[row]))

awesome_print([[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [2,3,0], [2,3,4]])
```

Output

```
+-+-+-+
|1|2|3| 
+-+-+-+
|1|2|3| 
+-+-+-+
|2|3|0| 
+-+-+-+
|2|3|4| 
+-+-+-+
```

In case you need to print data with non fixed size of subarrays

```
def awesome_print2(listOfLists):
    for row in range(len(listOfLists)):
        print('+' + '-+'*len(listOfLists[row]))
        print('|', end='')
        for col in range(len(listOfLists[row])):
            print(listOfLists[row][col], end='|')
        print()
        print('+' + '-+'*len(listOfLists[row]))
awesome_print2([[1,2,3,5], [1,2,3], [2,3,0,6,3], [2,3,4]])
```

Output:

```
+-+-+-+-+
|1|2|3|5|
+-+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+
|1|2|3|
+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+-+-+
|2|3|0|6|3|
+-+-+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+
|2|3|4|
+-+-+-+
```

Comment: This seems to have an extra space between each row. The last print statement should be outside the for loop to avoid this (unless that was intentional)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)